# Converting Razor project for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I've inherited a old website based on Razor/C#. It was originally deployed on a Windows system and we'd like to move to deploying on a Linux system using ASP.NET Core, which also supports Razor/C# so we can do move it to a public cloud host within our budget. However, I can't figure out how to convert the project from the ASP.NET 4.7/Razor 3.0 to ASP.NET Core 2.0 so I can run it. I've even tried loading up VS Code.

I've come across a few things that show the project structure has changed significantly - some files going away, other files coming in, etc.

To note: I don't normally use Windows any more. I only have Linux systems available to me.

Looking for tips, tools, etc.

Comment: Razor is just a View Engine, so I think you are talking about ASP.Net MVC. ASP.Net MVC is very different from .Net Core MVC, so you can't just copy-paste your code. It need to be rewriten.

Comment: You could read the [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

Comment: @Nikolaus I've looked through the docs, there's nothing there about converting the projects over. Typically VS handles that, but VS.Code doesn't even recognize it as a project.

Comment: @vasily.sib If I understand things correctly a very simple Razor site doesn't need ASP.NET MVC. I could be wrong, but from what I've been reading Razor exists in two forms - both under the older .NET 4 and the newer .NET Core - (a) a simple renderer of some basic content, and (b) a full-fledged MVC site. Docs seem to allude to this via how VS sets up the projects too.

I may have to rewrite it ultimately any way just b/c there is so much duplication of material. The codebase isn't really all that clean; but I wanted something to work with as a starting point first so I know my changes work.

Comment: There is a migration passage here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.0